# POST requires exactly one file upload per request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nestjs

I'm using nestjs and i want to upload to amazon s3, but every requests fails and error is: 
*POST requires exactly one file upload per request*

Here is my code implementation:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('policy', clientPayload.policy);
formData.append('key', clientPayload.key);
formData.append('x-amz-signature', clientPayload['x-amz-signature']);
formData.append('x-amz-algorithm', clientPayload['x-amz-algorithm']);
formData.append('x-amz-date', clientPayload['x-amz-date']);
formData.append('x-amz-credential', clientPayload['x-amz-credential']);
formData.append('success_action_status', '201');
formData.append('success_action_redirect', '');
formData.append('file', file.path);

try {
  const data = await this.http
    .post(AppConfig.awsServices.bucketUrl, formData, {
      headers: {
        'content-type':
          'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW',
      },
    })
    .toPromise();
```

And this is the response:

```
data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
  '<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><RequestId>D602243726B03B53</RequestId><HostId>qjLwo8jak8yb3iWOXp4fbqAw391MW7d/3/9r8AzqA20hAvYd1Kgj0PJIAEv+v9sMckixT9WtUoA=</HostId></Error>'
```

Here is image attachment as well:
[image: Code example]

And this is the request i'm trying to implement from docs:

https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/docs/book/upload/file.html

Comment: Try and remove the `content-type` header completely. Most request libraries should be able to set that correctly on their own. Specifying one yourself, escpecially with a boundary that is probably a completely different one than the one actually used when the request body gets assembled, is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Then throw following:
<Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition><RequestId>280B02688929A15A</RequestId><HostId>3k5t8ZMoh0B8rA6UNcfOHDyFy1y/IpLhi7GPhNDbbxYvPO8wqPW5DTsMRECS6qnKW/sPxWkoxPo=</HostId></Error>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not actually uploading a file, you're just passing a path to the file. Change it to something like:

```
const formData = new FormData();
// your .append() calls here
// instead of formData.append('file', file.path);
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('path-to-file'));
```

Also do not specify the content-type header manually, the httpService should take care of this:

```
 const data = await this.http
    .post(AppConfig.awsServices.bucketUrl, formData, { headers: { ...formData.getHeaders() })
    .toPromise();
```

Comment: But when i try to open fs.readFile and pass file.path i receive the file buffer?

Comment: If i remove header and send file it self this is what i got

(node:5028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: source.on is not a function

Comment: You could just use `fs.createReadStream()` and pass the stream to formData: `formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream('path-to-file'));`

Comment: That was good! But i hit following:

'<Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition><RequestId>AD927B21AA019D78</RequestId><HostId>HvPBQeOqV9HeLJnWnUkE4YvXbQS3WzUN8Umj4iC681Uny6eEzGrFH7Tu1yjoFl0vvrhXbIuIsME=</HostId></Error>'

Comment: Thats why i think i need to add content type header my self

Comment: Weird, as far as I know http-service should do this for you. But you can try doing it manually, see my edit.

Comment: G! really good mate, thanks a lot! Now i have this issue but i'll try to find why is happening:
  message: 'Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit',

Comment: Well, is your file bigger than the allowed limit? Anyway, that's a different issue now, please accept/close this question and post a new one :)